# How to combine a range and a determined value in a validation list?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a cell with a drop down list (using "Data Validation").

The list come from a named range in another worksheet.

I want the drop down to show the named range *and* another predefined value. So for example, if the range look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want the drop down to show:

```
1
2
3
4
17 (my predefined value)
```

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Validation Data to create list it's impossible, you will get the error message:
**You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for conditional formatting criteria.**

So I suggest you try to use code as a workaround to help you resolve this problem.

```
Sub SetDataValidation() '

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim rng As Range

'get range of named range

Set rng = WS.Range("NUMBER")

Dim ARR As Variant

ReDim ARR(1 To 1) As Variant

'add cell value from named range to an array

For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count

ARR(UBound(ARR)) = rng.Cells(i).Value

ReDim Preserve ARR(1 To UBound(ARR) + 1) As Variant

Next i

'add your predefined value to the array

ARR(UBound(ARR)) = 17

'set validation for B1 with the combined array

With WS.Range("B1").Validation

.Delete

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(ARR, ",")

End With

End Sub
```

In my sample, I named the range as NUMBER and get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours.  I had a named range `Dyn_ParamList_KillDate` with a list of dates `1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, etc...` .  This dynamic named range gets populated by a process and changes in size.  The problem is  sometimes the list would be empty an empty to dropdown was causing problems.

So for my solution I created another named range `Range_Writeback_ModelParamDate` that always has a value.  Then I changed the Data Validation List FROM `=Dyn_ParamList_KillDate` TO `=IF(Dyn_ParamList_KillDate<>"", Dyn_ParamList_KillDate, Range_Writeback_ModelParamDate)` .

Once I added this second range, ensured it always had a value, and changed the dropdown formula to use IF and pull from either range-- I started correctly getting the results based off of two ranges.  I hope this helps someone.

The idea for this solution came from here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/754454-you-may-not-use-reference-operators-array-constants-data-validation.html